# Save body request in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I am using **CSV file** which contains variables for my **XML requests**. I know how to see the request sent, but I would like to save each request in a separate file.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way seems to be using [Flexible File Writer](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FlexibleFileWriter/), you can save `requestData` into a file.

If you need more flexibility - for [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers you can do it with [Beanshell Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Listener) like:

1. Add Beanshell Listener to your Test Plan
2. Put the following code into the Listener's "Script" area

   ```
   import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

   String data = ctx.getCurrentSampler().getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue();
   int threadNum = ctx.getThreadNum();
   int loop = ctx.getVariables().getIteration();

   FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File("request-" + threadNum + "-" + loop + ".txt"),data);
   ```

You'll get files like `request-x-y.txt` generated in JMeter's "bin" folder where:

- `x` - JMeter Thread Number
- `y` - Current Loop Iteration ([Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) level)

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) article for more information on using Beanshell in JMeter tests.

Answer (score 1):

you should save the results as XML and turn on only the "Save Sampler Data (XML)"

Answer (score 0):

**Add > Listers> View Result Tree** 
In result tree click on config button and check the type of data thats has to be stored and provide the link to csv file.
Check the snapshot for more info.
[image: Config window snapshot]

Hope this helps.